# Subset the datatable by multiple user input filter separated by comma

Tags: shiny, datatable, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am quite new to R shiny and I am trying to build a small shiny app but I don't know where I went wrong.

I am trying to get multiple user input via text area to filter my table output. Moreover, i want to control the columns to show in the table as well. Code is running fine for showing the columns but it is working only with one input value in the text area, it is not working with multiple user inputs.

I want to filter the table output with multiple user inputs as well.
For example for this code snippet it should return table when I write "honda,audi,bmw" in the text area input.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
df <-mtcars

#ui
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Trial 1"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        #to take multiple user input
        textAreaInput(
          "text_input",
          label = "Write multiple input separated by comma"
          ),
        #to slect the columns to be added
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "somevalue",
          label = "Columns to add",
          choices = colnames(df),
          options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
          multiple = TRUE
        ),
        #action button tot show the table
        actionBttn(
          "show_table",
          label = "Show",
          size =  "sm",
          color = "default",
          block = TRUE
        ),
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel("Table", DT::dataTableOutput("table")),
                    tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary"))
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    data <- observeEvent(input$show_table,{
      text_input <- trimws(strsplit(input$text_input, ",")[[1]])
    output$summary <- renderPrint({
      summary(data())
    })
    output$table <- DT::renderDT({
      df_sub <- df[df$make %chin% input$text_input, input$somevalue]
      #df_sub = df[ ,input$somevalue]
      datatable(df_sub,
                caption = "PLease enter the changes by double clicking the cell",
                editable = 'cell')
    })
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Try with `df$make %chin% text_input` instead of `input$text_input`. The last is the unspilt and untrimmed input string.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a 'make' variable in the data. I guess you refer to the first word of the row name as the make of the car. Then the strings you entered could be matched with the make of the car.

```
server = function(input, output,session) {

data <- observeEvent(input$show_table,{
  brand <- word(rownames(df), 1)
  text_input <- strsplit(input$text_input, ",")[[1]]
  df_sub <- df[brand %in% text_input, input$somevalue]
  
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(df_sub)
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(df_sub,
              caption = "PLease enter the changes by double clicking the cell",
              editable = 'cell')
  })
  output$test <- renderText({ 
    text_input
  })
})}
```